# How to select a substring from a column value in mysql 5.7?

Tags: sql, mysql

the selected values of my query are like

```
gruppo-1_some_text
gruppo-12_some_other_text
```

But I'd like to have only

```
some_text
some_other_text
```

So I would need to substract `'gruppo-\d+_'` from the initially selected strings.

I don't have `REGEXP_REPLACE` and the like on mysql 5.7.39, so I can't figure out how to do it, if ever possible...

Comment: What's the pointng in tagging your question with `regex` to attract experts in regex if you know you cannot use? Other string manipulation function do exist however. Have you even researched anything?

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING(column FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', column)) ... WHERE column REGEXP '^gruppo-\d+_' ...`

Comment: @Stu I didn't know there are NO other regexp possibilities. And yes I searched and found anything useful at the moment. If you know about other sql functions that can help, please answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, txt, SUBSTRING(txt FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', txt)), txt REGEXP '^gruppo-\\d+_.*'
FROM test
```

| id | txt | SUBSTRING(txt FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', txt)) | txt REGEXP '^gruppo-\d+_.*' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gruppo-1_text_1 | text_1 | 1 |
| 2 | gruppo-12_text_12 | text_12 | 1 |
| 3 | gruppo-_text_none | text_none | 0 |
| 4 | gruppo-44s_text_not_number | text_not_number | 0 |
| 5 | gruppo-555 _text_not_number_too | text_not_number_too | 0 |
| 6 | gruppo-1234567890_text_long | text_long | 1 |
| 6 | gruppo-0000000000_text_long_zerofill | text_long_zerofill | 1 |

```
SELECT id, txt, SUBSTRING(txt FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', txt))
FROM test
WHERE txt REGEXP '^gruppo-\\d+_.*'
```

| id | txt | SUBSTRING(txt FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', txt)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gruppo-1_text_1 | text_1 |
| 2 | gruppo-12_text_12 | text_12 |
| 6 | gruppo-1234567890_text_long | text_long |
| 6 | gruppo-0000000000_text_long_zerofill | text_long_zerofill |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hKe8442I)

Comment: In fact, the only expression I need, and it works perfectly (thank you again) is `SUBSTRING(txt FROM 1 + LOCATE('_', txt))`. I didn't immediately found that syntax in docs, so I explain here for future readers: it takes a substring of txt starting from  the position of the first occurrence of '_' + 1. So for example in gruppo-12_text_12 will be 1+10=11. Maybe slightly more clear if written like `SUBSTRING(txt FROM LOCATE('_', txt) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select txt 
  ,case when (txt regexp 'gruppo-[0-9]{1,}_')=1 then
    substring(substring(txt,length('gruppo-')+1,100)
     ,instr(substring(txt,length('gruppo-')+1,100),'_')+1,100) 
   end s
  ,case when (txt regexp 'gruppo-[0-9]{1,}_')=1 then
    substring(substring(txt,length('gruppo-')+1,100)
     ,1,instr(substring(txt,length('gruppo-')+1,100),'_')-1) 
   end n
from test
```

```
create table test (id int,txt varchar(100));
insert into test values
 (1,'gruppo-1_some_text')
,(2,'gruppo-12_some_other_text')
,(3,'gruppo-_some_next_text')
,(4,'gruppo-44s_ome_next_text')
,(5,'gruppo-555 _some_next_text')
,(6,'gruppo-1234567890_some_next_text')
```

| txt | s | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gruppo-1_some_text | some_text | 1 |
| gruppo-12_some_other_text | some_other_text | 12 |
| gruppo-_some_next_text | null | null |
| gruppo-44s_ome_next_text | null | null |
| gruppo-555 _some_next_text | null | null |
| gruppo-1234567890_some_next_text | some_next_text | 1234567890 |